# Microsoft Bot Framework - Twilio Voice and SMS support

Tags: twilio, botframework

Microsoft Bot Framework - Twilio Voice and SMS support.
I am using Node js-SDK3. I created bot and twilio app. I am not sure how to integrate the same?

I need example code for integration.

Comment: What steps have you followed to connect your bot to Twillio? Are you encountering any errors? I'd recommend taking a look at this guide that details how to [Connect a bot to Twilio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-twilio?view=azure-bot-service-4.0).

Comment: I am not sure how to start even.

Comment: Have you deployed your app to Azure, and do you have a bot registration?

Comment: Yes I registered

Comment: And have you added Twillio as a Channel in the Bot Registration?